# Applying Vite RegEx path alias-- of file extension-- to Typescript?

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

I'm evaluating a number of different CSS approaches in a toy website, and I'm using individual files with different extensions, e.g:

- Linaria - `component.linaria.ts`
- StyleX - `component.stylex.ts`
- Emotion - `component.emotion.ts`

etc

In the component, I can use `import './component.style'` and then, in Vite, I can configure an alias:

```
export default defineConfig({
  resolve: {
    alias: [
      { find: /^(.*)\.styles$/, replacement: '$1.linaria' },
    ],
  },
});
```

The trouble is, this doesn't work in Typescript-- the module doesn't resolve, as the file doesn't (obviously) exist.

AFAICT, what I need is for `paths` to support `regex`, or, at the very least, extension mapping.  But that's not avaiable.  There are a couple of [open](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29245) [requests](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27298), but both have no response.

Am I just out of luck here?  Open to solutions or alternatives.